# Is there an optimized and efficient way of doing this?

Tags: c#, networking, stream, byte, flush

I am wondering on how I can optimize this method. Is there any alternative to add bytes on a list without overwriting it?

```
    public void Flush(NetworkStream netStream)
    {
        MinecraftPacketWriter writer = new MinecraftPacketWriter();
        writer.WriteVarInt(buffer.Count);
        byte[] lengthbytes = writer.Buffer.ToArray();
        byte[] bufferbytes = buffer.ToArray();

        byte[] doublebuffer = lengthbytes.Concat(bufferbytes).ToArray();
        writer.Reset();

        buffer = doublebuffer.ToList<byte>();

        RawFlush(netStream);
    }
```

This is my whole class.

```
public class MinecraftPacketWriter
{
    private List<byte> buffer = new List<byte>();

    public List<byte> Buffer { get { return buffer; } }

    public void Reset()
    {
        buffer.Clear();
    }
    //.....
    public void Write(byte b)
    {
        buffer.Add(b);
    }

    public void RawFlush(NetworkStream netStream)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Buffer Bytes Count: {0}", buffer.Count);

        netStream.Write(buffer.ToArray(), 0, buffer.Count);
        Reset();
    }

    public void Flush(NetworkStream netStream)
    {
        MinecraftPacketWriter writer = new MinecraftPacketWriter();
        writer.WriteVarInt(buffer.Count);
        byte[] lengthbytes = writer.Buffer.ToArray();
        byte[] bufferbytes = buffer.ToArray();

        byte[] doublebuffer = lengthbytes.Concat(bufferbytes).ToArray();
        writer.Reset();

        buffer = doublebuffer.ToList<byte>();

        RawFlush(netStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what you're trying to do. The code is quite unreadable. Making some assumptions, it looks like you're trying to send a length identifier followed by that many arbitrary bytes to a network endpoint. I would suggest looking at this class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: check codereview in google.

Comment: Basically, I am looking for a better way to add bytes at the start of the list without overwriting the ones that were at that posiiton.

Comment: Why do you want to add the bytes to the list? From the code you posted, all you do is write those bytes out immediately after. Why bother with the modification to the buffer you want to write? Why not just have `RawFlush()` write the bytes representing the count directly to the `NetworkStream`, followed immediately by the `buffer` bytes? (Please note that not only is the code example not [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) clearly illustrating the question, you don't even show the implementation of `WriteVarInt()`).

Comment: I write multiple data so the list holds all the other datas. Since the third-party app wants me to send a length packet to be the first packet, i had to use the following methods.